# Apply a programmatic pan with achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

Is there a way I can apply a pan from code?  I want my pie chart to initially display a little off center (down a little bit).  Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [renderer](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/package-frame.html) API. I guess you should use `setInitialRange(double[] range, int scale)` function, but I can't be sure from your question: do you mean to 'offset' initially displayed data **inside** graph or to change whole chart position (a little below) ?

Maybe posting an image could help to understand your need